# AngularJS: Simply passing a value to a directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a very basic problem: I cannot pass a value, or anything else, to a directive's template and have it display in the template, despite having tried many examples. I have created a punker to demonstate the problem, after boiling it down to the most basic example.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/03IfoCazo1cLCsRIQ4Lh?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    a<exampleDirective fancyname="Hello">-</exampleDirective>b
  </body>
</html>

angular.module('myapp', [])
    .directive('exampleDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                fancyname: "@"
            },
            template: '1<div><i>2{{fancyname}}2</i></div>1'
        };
    });
```

It seems that the template is not loading at all, though at one point it was and {{fancyname}} was not showing the value of "Hello".

Any help to this directive NOOB is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy mistake when u r learning...

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .directive('exampleDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                fancyname: "@"
            },
            template: '1<div><i>2{{fancyname}}2</i></div>1'
        };
    });
```

Equals this HTML

```
<example-directive fancyname="Hello"></example-directive>
```

Your forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yI7bu6nsD43uNfzNcsgz)

Comment: Sten, your a lifesaver. Im noticing that this fix also applies to camelCased scope params. paramTwo = param-two. Thank you so much!